# How do I make an EditText raise along with the keyboard when in focus?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Just like in texting applications, I want the keyboard to push the dialog box up when it raises. The issue I'm currently having is that the keyboard actually raises over my dialog box and the screen does not scroll.

Here's what I want: (Don't have enough reputation to post images)

[Image one (Before)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnOWb.png)

[Image two (After)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjsLd.png)

See how nicely it raises? How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Android SDK should be able to handle that automatically once you put focus on the editText, see here for info: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `RelativeLayout` and place your `EditText` using `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` it should then raise automatically when the keyboard is shown.

Comment: Excellent! This is what I wanted, thank you very much.

Now, in the event that I have a button underneath the EditText that I want to be raised with it, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: In relative layouts you can specify things like `android:layout_above="@id/id_of_other_view"` and `android:layout_below="@id/id_of_other_view"`.

Answer (score 2):

//try windowsoftinput mode in your manifest xml file.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

> adjustResize  0x10     Always resize the window: the content area of the 
>       window is reduced to make room for the soft input area

.

[ref this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowSoftInputMode)

Comment: Just place this indie the <activity> tag you want the layout to be moved up when you press the edittext