# EditText hide when type a text?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-edittext

I have a Fragment with an EditText. When I try type a text the EditText hides and keyboard go to front of EditText and I can't type the text. I tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` but I think this doesn't works with Fragments.

How can I solve it ?

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/fundo_telas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/convite_batalha"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/title_convite"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_agenda"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/etEmail"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:inputType="textEmailSubject"
            android:hint="Digite o email do convidado"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btConvidar"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_convidar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**DrawerLayout with AdView**

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/dl">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp">
            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                    android:id="@+id/adView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    ads:adSize="BANNER"
                    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
                    android:background="#000"
                    >
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>




   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/lv"
       android:layout_width="250dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#e9ba68"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#ac453c"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
       >
   </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Is this layout in ListView?

Comment: are you sure it goes to hide state, i have a doubt because you set white color in background.

Comment: Can you send a print screen?

Comment: show ur activity in manifest...

Comment: I think the problem is with AdView. When AdView are showing the EditText hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [android-developers](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html) if you go to `manifest.xml` and change your Activity configuration to :

```
<activity name="YourActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
    ...
</activity>
```

the problem will be solved.

**Another solution** according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8911780/1638739) is to change the container layout to `RelativeLayout` and set `EditText` with `alignParentBottom="true"`.

---

About the AdView problem, just wrap all of the contents in a `LinearLayout` and put it along with your AdView inside a single RelativeLayout, then set AdView to `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and for the other `LinearLayout` set attribute `android:layout_above="@id/adView"`, for an illustration code, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9150048/1638739).

Comment: I have an AdMob(AdView) in my app. This AdView is align on bottom. When AdView showing does hide EditText.

Comment: So, the keyboard problem doesn't exist anymore but now the AdView blocks the `EditText`?

Comment: I added my DrawerLayout with AdView

Comment: well, I think my updated answer will solve this problem, as it will make the whole layout that contains the EditText above the AdView all time, just try it

Comment: I did your suggestion but doesn't works. I edited the post with changes. Could you help me ?

Comment: well, where is the RelativeLayout you created?

Comment: I solved the problem. I added a ScrollView and works. Thanks a lot.